# Having Trouble Segmentation Fault in C

Tags: c, shell, sorting, segmentation-fault

I'm having issues with a small portion of my program that makes a list of random numbers and then shell sorts them, right now it will not finish computing, which makes me think that the loop isn't finishing. I WAS getting segmentation fault errors but I managed to fix that by fixing some issues with how I was accessing my Array. Anyways, a fresh set of eyes may be good for me. Sorry if tabbing is off.

I think the issue is with the shell_results array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{

  /*Initialize Random Array*/
  int *unsorted_list[1000000];
  int random_number;
  int i;

  for(i=0; i<1000000; i++){

    srand ( time(NULL) );
    random_number = rand();
    unsorted_list[i] = random_number; 
  }

  //Do C Shell Sort 
  double shell_results[10][2];

  double clock_diff;
  int j=1000000;
  clock_t t0, t1;
  int k;

  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    /* Sort the list using shellSort and take the time difference */ 
    t0 = clock();
    shellSort(*unsorted_list, j);
    t1= clock();

    /*Take difference in time*/
    clock_diff = (t1 - t0); 

    /*Add time and list length to the results array*/
    shell_results[i][0] = (double)j;
    shell_results[i][1] = clock_diff;


    /*Check to make sure the array has been sorted*/
    checkSort(*unsorted_list, j);

    /*Re-initialize a longer array*/
    //j+=1000000;       
    for(k=0; k<j; k++){

      srand ( time(NULL) );
      random_number = rand();
      unsorted_list[k] = random_number; 
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

void shellSort(int *A, int n)
{
  int gap , i , j , temp; 

  for (gap = n/2; gap>0; gap /=2)
    for (i=gap; i<n; i++)
      for(j = i-gap; j>=0 && &A[j] > &A[j+gap]; j-=gap){
        temp = &A[j]; 
        A[j] = &A[j + gap]; 
        A[j + gap] = temp; 
      }
}

void checkSort(int *A, int n)
{
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(&A[i]>&A[i+1]){
      printf("Error in sorting \n");
      break;    
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Answer (score 2):

For a start, the line

```
int *unsorted_list[1000000];
```

is using pointers

Surely

```
int unsorted_list[1000000];
```

would be better considering when you fill it with

```
unsorted_list[i] = random_number;
```

PS: Only need to use `srand` once.

Answer (score 0):

> Sorry if tabbing is off.

Can you do anything about it? If not, no need to be sorry. If so, do it.

`int *unsorted_list[1000000];` What is the type of unsorted_list? Array of one million pointers to int.

`unsorted_list[i] = random_number;` What is the type of unsorted_list[i]? Pointer to int. Are you sure it's suitable to be assigning an int value to a pointer to int object? Isn't your compiler warning you about this line? It'd be nice if you'd tell us about warnings, in the future!

`shellSort(*unsorted_list, j);` Having corrected the type of unsorted_list, what is the type of `*unsorted_list`? int. What type does shellSort expect? Pointer to int.

```
    for(j = i-gap; j>=0 && &A[j] > &A[j+gap]; j-=gap){
        temp = &A[j]; 
        A[j] = &A[j + gap]; 
        A[j + gap] = temp; 
    }
```

What is the type of &A[j]? What is the type of temp? The warnings your compiler is giving you here are *not good*, in fact warnings *are never good*. Don't ignore them!

Which book are you reading?